# Why intellij doesn't provide functionality to store SSH sessions

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, intellij-15

I've just installed latest Intellij IDEA 15.0.1. There is provided tool to connect using SSH session. I use connection using private key. Connection is successful, but my sessions isn't stored after close connection. How to make idea save host and primary key location?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set up ssh connection at `Tools | Deployment | Configuration`.

Add new server with plus button. Enter name and select [`SFTP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) as a type.

Now you can enter host, username and password (or key pair).

Next time you'll select `Tools | Start SSH session` there should be your server name.

Comment: I get 'SFTP host is invalid' warning. I'm using host like staging-2.com, tried deploy@staging-2.com - same result (

Comment: I had redundant space at the end, my bad